# When using Webby/Compass Integration what directory do the *.sass files go in?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, webby

I just setup [Webby/Compass integration](https://github.com/Compass/compass/wiki/webby-integration).
(https://github.com/Compass/compass/wiki/webby-integration)

Where do I put my Compass/Sass source files, and in what directory do they get
output as stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your SASS files wherever you want (under the 'content/' directory). So if the directory containing your CSS files is 'content/css', then put them there.

The only important thing is that you set the metadata part correctly, at the top of the SASS file itself. Like this:

```
$ cat content/css/site.sass 
---
filter: sass
extension: css
layout: nil
---
[..cut..]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set the source-file yourself, from the documentation:

```
Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.project_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  config.sass_dir = File.join('src', 'stylesheets' )
end
```

It looks like it defaults to "src/stylesheets". When you build it it will probably get rendered to "output/css/" but I never used webby myself so im not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah I looked at this too...That's not it...see post bellow

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it in [this repository](http://github.com/macournoyer/macournoyer.com/blob/43a1be1ef4b36bf2c292f4a060ff2623d1b912e3/content/stylesheets/ie.sass)

Apparently it belongs in the ./content/stylesheets directory of your webby project, and is output to the ./output/stylesheets directory.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to add the filter bit and extension attributes  to the top of the file as well!  Otherwise it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

What perplexes me is "why" it works this way. Why File.join? It looks like the default "src" is being replaced by "stylesheets" rather than joining a new string. Curious.